# OpenCover not finding PDBs on the build server

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, xunit, opencover

I have the following command on my local machine:

```
C:\Tools\opencover\OpenCover.Console.exe 
  -register 
  -target:C:\local-source\develop\Lib\NuGetPackages\xunit.runner.console.2.4.0\tools\net462\xunit.console.exe 
  -targetargs:"C:\local-source\Develop\Src\LN.B.Tests.Integration\bin\Release\LN.B.Tests.Integration.dll -noshadow" 
  -output:TestCoverage.xml 
  -log:Verbose 
  "-filter:+[*]* -[*xunit*]* -[*RefEmit_InMemoryManifestModule*]* -[*AutoFixture*]*"
```

The command displays the following output, which is expected:

```
Visited Classes 1103 of 5472 (20.16)
Visited Methods 9832 of 65663 (14.97)
Visited Points 25472 of 318612 (7.99)
Visited Branches 13949 of 209530 (6.66)

==== Alternative Results (includes all methods including those without corresponding source) ====
Alternative Visited Classes 1324 of 6608 (20.04)
Alternative Visited Methods 10689 of 73849 (14.47)
```

Now, I want to run the same command on a Build server targeting a dll that is generated by a daily build:

```
C:\Tools\opencover\OpenCover.Console.exe 
  -register 
  -target:D:\Build\XG5\BuildDeployDev1\Lib\NuGetPackages\xunit.runner.console.2.4.0\tools\net462\xunit.console.exe 
  -targetargs:"Src\LN.B.Tests.Integration\bin\Release\LN.B.Tests.Integration.dll -noshadow" 
  -output:TestCoverage.xml 
  -log:Verbose 
  "-filter:+[*]* -[*xunit*]* -[*RefEmit_InMemoryManifestModule*]* -[*AutoFixture*]*"
```

For some reason, the output is different, and I can't wrap my head around why:

```
Visited Classes 61 of 405 (15.06)
Visited Methods 591 of 4729 (12.5)
Visited Points 3295 of 26321 (12.52)
Visited Branches 2017 of 16924 (11.92)

==== Alternative Results (includes all methods including those without corresponding source) ====
Alternative Visited Classes 67 of 458 (14.63)
Alternative Visited Methods 635 of 5341 (11.89)
```

Looking at the log file, I get a lot of `Cannot instrument D:\Jenkins\workspace\XG5_OpenCover2.2\Src\LN.B.Tests.Integration\bin\Release\LN.Common.Repository.dll as no PDB/MDB could be loaded` and the output lists my dlls as: `MissingPDB`

- My user has admin privileges on both machines is admin
- Opencover version: 4.6.519.0 (Same behavior with the newer version)
- I verified that the built pdbs are "PDB only"
- I have tried `-register:user`, `-register:Path32`, and `-register:Path64`
- I have tried running `regsvr32 "C:\Tools\opencover\x64\OpenCover.Profiler.dll"` and `"C:\Tools\opencover\x32\OpenCover.Profiler.dll"`
- I have reviewed: https://github.com/opencover/opencover/blob/master/main/OpenCover.Documentation/Usage.pdf

What else can I try to fix this issue? I think I've exhausted all the options.

Comment: I assume the build server is creating a 'release' build and so your PDBs are 'PDB only'. You should change the PDBs to be Full i.e. the same as your Debug build settings. You can test this out by building the release build locally and replicating the build server issue and then change the PDB settings.

Comment: @ShaunWilde I am trying to reproduce it locally, but what is crazy is that my dlls are set to "PDB Only" in my local environment, and OpenCover is able to generate results.

Comment: I'd look to remote onto the Jenkins box after the build has run and see if you can run the commands.